# Force int64 overflow in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm porting a C++ library to Ruby and I'm having trouble replicating the int64 overflow behaviour.

If I do this multiplication on bash (or c++) I get a negative number because if [2^63 value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807):

```
> let "iv=1436440203*833471*380*1436440203" ; echo $iv
-4353333299339738780
```

But Ruby converts it to a BigNumber and gives the expected result:

```
[1] pry(main)> 1436440203*833471*380*1436440203
=> 653505419248345501939646820
[2] pry(main)> (1436440203*833471*380*1436440203).class
=> Bignum
```

How can I force Ruby to replicate C++/bash behaviour?

Also, I already looked at this question ([Emulating int64 overflows in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250216/emulating-int64-overflows-in-ruby)) and I think it's not the same.

Doing the mod operator also won't give me a negative result

```
[3] pry(main)> (1436440203*833471*380*1436440203) % 2**64
=> 14093410774369812836

[4] pry(main)> (1436440203*833471*380*1436440203) % 2**63
=> 4870038737515037028
```

Comment: Did you look at the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7250280/102937) on that question?  The answer is buried there, but it is there.  Ruby never overflows, so you have to mod your number with 2^63 to see if it's too large.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. I edited the question to include that example

Comment: Ehm, if you want a negative number, you have to do the math to make it negative, though that's seldom the desired result, even with a language that has that behavior.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The desired result is the same that the C++ function that I'm importing returns. I don't see how this can be a duplicated question.

Comment: You're not addressing the comments I'm making.  Are you having trouble figuring out the math?

Comment: Not really, I was just curious if I could replicate that behaviour in Ruby telling him to not switch to a bignum. Thanks for the help though

Comment: [How do you calculate integers overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15217456)

Comment: C++ is a bad example since signed integer overflow in C++ is undefined. But `[integer].pack('q').unpack('q')[0]` should do what you want. It isn't fast though.

Comment: exactly what I want @cremno. If you place it in an answer I'll mark as accepted.